# Stripe custom storefront at adobe commerce (magento) graphql - edit cards

Tags: stripe-payments, gql

we are building Stripe custom storefront at adobe commerce

[docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connectors/adobe-commerce/custom-storefront)

Q1.
this code returns cards but no customer names / address.
how to retrieve them?

```
mutation {
  listStripePaymentMethods {
    id
    created
    type
    fingerprint
    label
    icon
    cvc
    brand
    exp_month
    exp_year
  }
}
```

Q2.
there is addStripePaymentMethod  examples.
it misses  customer names / address also.
how to add/ edit card, including customer name and billing address?\ using stripe gql?

Q3. is there fuller documentation on stripe gql available?